# Label span tag is not working properly in chrome

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is the output I get in chrome.
I have menu in the header. For the navigation to work  good in mobile, I have added below code. the navigation works fine. but the label in the menu on top is not displaying properly in chrome. It works good in IE.
HTML code:

```
<input type='checkbox'/> 
<label>&#8801;<span>MENU</span></label>
```

CSS code:

```
#menu input,#menu label{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:block}
```

The desired output is triplebar symbol MENU
what I get in chrome is triplebar symbol M
                                         E
                                         N
                                         U

Comment: Seems to be working okay for me. could you provide some more of the surrounding code if theres any or a screenshot?

Comment: Since this code work as is, post a working code snippet that reproduces the issue you have

Comment: @ree , I have added the image of the output I get in chrome. please refer.

Comment: Add `white-space: nowrap` to your `#menu label` rule

Comment: @LGSon, It works. thanks.

Comment: Ehm... @LGSon How did you know that would have a chance of working, if the OP's code already works as is?

Comment: @MrLister Eeeeee, experience ?? ... ;) ... according to OP's posted image the text MENU flowed vertical in Chrome (which it shouldn't), so it was a wild qualified guess :)

Comment: @vij I am still curious what you did that caused the code to work OK in IE, but not in Chrome. I mean, I managed to do it, but only by cheating. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deLyz4hg/1/), where I had to write`{word-break: break-all; -ms-word-break: normal}` to pull it off. Is that what you did?